# Calculating the Picard group of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ in an elementary way

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

I have to explain the Picard group to some people that doesn't know the concept of sheaf. So is there a method to calculate $Pic(\mathbb{C}P^1)$ without sheaf theory? Is there a simple and easy proof that $Pic(\mathbb{C}P^1) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I don't know much algebraic geometry, but I suspect this is just the number of times the copy of $\mathbb C$ rotates around the origin as it goes around the circle $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: Dear @GrumpyParsnip: $\mathbf P^1$ is topologically a sphere, not a circle (it is the Riemann sphere)

Comment: @ArthurStuart First of all, what is your definition of Picard group? If you are defining it as $H^1 (X, \mathscr{O}_X^{\times})$ then there's not going to be much chance of explaining it without sheaf theory!

Comment: @Bruno: Oops! I don't know what I was thinking. That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can try describing it using the language of divisors, which is easy to understand. It's also how the Picard group was first defined historically.

Given a divisor $D$ on $\mathbf P^1$, you can find a rational function with divisor $D$ precisely when $\deg D = 0$. Thus, $\deg D$, which is an integer, can be thought of as measuring the obstruction to the problem of finding a rational function with divisor $D$.

In other words, the degree function induces an isomorphism

$$\text{Pic}(\mathbf P^1) =\{\text{Divisors on }\mathbf P^1\}/\{\text{Principal divisors on } \mathbf P^1\} \overset{\sim}{\to} ­\mathbf Z.$$